# How to set Priority level of main thread

Tags: multithreading, delphi

I have an application that runs 44*3=132 threads + main thread and each 3 threads represent a tcp client network. Freeing all this takes a lot of time on app finalization so I'm looking for a way to make this faster.

Only one way I know - setting the priority level. So each thread has priority level = normal. How should I set the priority level of the main thread to the highest possible level so it frees all other threads faster?

Comment: Changing a thread priority is almost never the correct solution to an optimization problem.

Comment: When it's the only way you know, it is the best solution. Why don't you write your better alternative?

Comment: `SetThreadPriority(GetCurrentThread, THREAD_PRIORITY_HIGHEST)`  ?

Comment: Does freeing take time? I mean noticable time? How much time are we talking about anyway? Could it be something else that's causing the perceived delay?

Comment: Elevating the main thread priority may have negative impact on other threads, resulting in worse performance. This is not the right way to go. Let your threads check a global flag regularly and set FreeOnTerminate to true for the threads. When your main thread sets the flag, all threads will terminate by them self. They could even post a message to confirm termination.

Comment: @netboy, the right way is (1) profile your app, to better understand what is taking the time and (2) reconsider the problem domain. The reason I don't just write in the answer is that I don't have your code or your understanding of your business problem. I have two paragraphs from you, one of which mostly describes a "solution" which I think is a bad idea. I can't just look at the two sentences in your first paragraph and magically divine a solution for you. I can, however, suggest that you reconsider the problem. At the *very least,* you should show your code here.

Comment: I have an application currently running with between 50 and 100 threads on a 9 year-old single core Pentium P4. It usually takes less than one second to close, so I suspect it is the way you are doing things, not the thread priority that is the issue.

Comment: -1 for an [XY problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=542341).

Comment: Rob: IMO, -1 because it's an XY problem is a bit harsh, especially to a newcomer. (But, thanks for the link to the XY problem discussion. I'd never encountered the term before and like it!)

Comment: @Robert, voting applies to the *question*, not the *person*, and in this case, the question is asked poorly. XY problems are typically hard to answer because *Y* doesn't make any sense. Here *Y* is well defined (which is why I answered it), but the question is muddled because *X* gets in the way. If Netboy removes the part about *X*, I'd rescind my vote.

Answer (score 8):

I'd say that you need to look at what your threads are doing, and ask them to do it in parallel. In my service app, which can have hundreds of threads (some with child threads), I have a loop on shutdown which is effectively:

```
for I := 0 to ThreadCount - 1 do
    Threads[I].Terminate;
for I := 0 to ThreadCount - 1 do
    Threads[I].WaitFor;
for I := 0 to ThreadCount - 1 do
    Threads[I].Free;
```

The threads close themselves down in a timely manner on being terminated, but by asking them all to shut down first, and then waiting for them, it can all happen that much faster. And of course if the first thread is the last to close, then the middle loop there will be very fast as it will always only take as long as the slowest thread to close.

If your problem is not helped by this, then we need to see your code I think.

Comment: `for I := 0 to ThreadCount` ? Are you sure? Or it's better: `for I := 0 to ThreadCount-1`?

Answer (score 6):

The way to change the priority of the main thread is to call [`SetThreadPriority`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686277.aspx) on it. For the handle, just use `GetCurrentThread` — you don't need to open a real handle.

That probably won't have any effect on the problem you're trying to solve, but you didn't ask how to solve your problem; you asked how to adjust thread priority. If you want to know how to make your threads get freed more quickly, then next time, ask about that instead.